# replace includeGraphics with inline-image

Tags: graphics, includegraphics

In my tex-file there are included images:

```
\includegraphics[width=\someVar]{filename}
```

I want to create a self-containing file, using [this](https://mrw.sh/templates/inline-images/src/branch/master/examples)

```
\inlineimg{whateverfilename}{base64encodedImage}
```

How can I preserve the width-setting?

Comment: Apart from 1)editing the sty file or 2) writing a renewed command the simplest is to ensure the default size is the one you want that should be easily set by the encoded resolution if png it will be in the chunks if bmp in the header and for jpeg in the exif seems a lot of trouble to encode then use a roundtrip package to insert the decoded stream into  the same document why bother except for proof of concept?